# Remove geolocation from text

Tags: r

Is there any possible way to remove `country` names and `cities` from a text without having a list?

Example data:

```
data.frame(text = c("I love to travel to London"), stringAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I can't think of a way of doing this with 100% accuracy without a lookup list.

Comment: Here's a messy way around lists: if your data is properly formatted e.g. London has 'L' in upper case, you can grab all such occurrences and compare them against a reverse geolocation API or address validation API to see if you get a result. As long as you get a non-null result, it's a city/country and you can remove it from your text. Eg. 'London' could return several results - London Ontario, London UK etc. Be careful though that some APIs (e.g. Google) will try to find the 'nearest match' to what it thinks you're asking for - this would not work for obvious reasons.

Comment: Lists are definitely much easier - if you don't want to hard code one, you can scrape it from an online source - do it programatically so that each time your script runs, it gets the latest data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use a list like this:

```
library(maps)
head(world.cities)
```

```
                name country.etc   pop   lat  long capital
1 Abasan al-Jadidah   Palestine  5629 31.31 34.34       0
2 Abasan al-Kabirah   Palestine 18999 31.32 34.35       0
3       Abdul Hakim    Pakistan 47788 30.55 72.11       0
4 Abdullah-as-Salam      Kuwait 21817 29.36 47.98       0
5              Abud   Palestine  2456 32.03 35.07       0
6            Abwein   Palestine  3434 32.03 35.20       0
```

This is a quick attempt to accomplish what you're looking for.

```
df <- data.frame(text = c("I love to travel to London",
                          "Germany was a fun country to visit."), stringAsFactors = FALSE)

replace_cities_countries <- function(string, replacement) {
  library(maps)
  data(world.cities)
  patterns <- unique(c(world.cities$name, world.cities$country.etc))
  for (i in seq_along(patterns))
    string <- gsub(patterns[i], replacement, string, perl=TRUE)
  string
}

sapply(df$text, replace_cities_countries, replacement='HOORAY!')
```